# How can I hide jQuery email attach more button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I implemented email attachments features which is working fine.
But when I click on attach more button , I am keep displaying the browse button.Which is not good.
Initially, I display browse button  but when I click on attach more button I don't want to display the browse button again, instead it should automatically pop up the file to choose.

How can I do that. Please see the image attachment.

html code

```
<div class="col-sm-10">
              <div class="element">
                <label>Attachment</label>
                <span class="upload_file_button"><input type="file" name="upload_file1" id="upload_file1"/></span>
                </div>
                <div id="moreImageUpload"></div>
                <div id="moreImageUploadLink" style="display:none;margin-left: 10px;">
                <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="attachMore" class="fa fa-plus"> Attach More</a>
                </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

jquery /javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// onclick browse button attach the file id and show the attachmore link

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("input[id^='upload_file']").each(function() {
  var id = parseInt(this.id.replace("upload_file", ""));
  $("#upload_file" + id).change(function() { 
   if ($("#upload_file" + id).val() != "") {
   $("#moreImageUploadLink").show();
   }
  });
});
var upload_number = 2;
$('#attachMore').click(function() {
//add more file. Everytime clicking on attachmore link show the browse button also attach more as well.
var moreUploadTag = ''
 moreUploadTag += '<div class="element"><label for="upload_file"' + upload_number + '>Upload File ' + upload_number + '</label>';
 moreUploadTag += '<span class="upload_file_button"><input type="file" id="upload_file' + upload_number + '" name="upload_file' + upload_number + '"/></span>';
 moreUploadTag += '&nbsp;<a href="javascript:del_file(' + upload_number + ')" style="cursor:pointer;" onclick="return confirm(\"Are you really want to delete ?\")">Delete ' + upload_number + '</a></div>';
 $('<dl id="delete_file' + upload_number + '">' + moreUploadTag + '</dl>').fadeIn('slow').appendTo('#moreImageUpload');
 upload_number++;
 });
});

function del_file(eleId) {
 var ele = document.getElementById("delete_file" + eleId);
 ele.parentNode.removeChild(ele);
}
</script>
```

[image]

Comment: if m understand right . you don't want to add buttons instead  on add more click you want to open file picker ? right ?

Comment: Yes, thats what I want to do. Initially I'll display the browse button. After attaching 1 file and clicking on the attachmore I just want to open the file picker .

When I click on attach more it should keep adding files in the same row

Comment: here it open a file picker .

Comment: yes . here i only provide how to trigger event .. rest of code is much work .. if i am able to complete will update code

Comment: ok i will try .. but better you can check this http://www.a2zwebhelp.com/multiple-file-upload .. its same like you want